# Jsoup Remove parent element

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

I want to delete the tag that contains app_paragraph attribute.

But children should not be deleted.

**Code**

```
String url = "https://someurl";

Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(url);

Document html = conn.get();

Elements rawContent = html.select(".writing_view_box div[style]").last().children();
rawContent.select("#dcappheader").remove();

System.out.print(rawContent);
```

**Current Output (rawContent)**

```
<p></p>
<div app_paragraph="Dc_App_text_0" app_editorno="0">
 <div>
  Title
 </div>
</div>
<p xss="removed"></p>
<div app_paragraph="Dc_App_Img_0" app_editorno="1">
 <img src="image_src">
</div>
<p></p>
<div app_paragraph="Dc_App_text_1" app_editorno="2"></div>
```

**Expect Output**

```
<p></p>
<div>
 Title
</div>
<p xss="removed"></p>
 <img src="image_src">
<p></p>
```

Comment: okay, I understand. But what did you try so far? Where are you stuck? To me it seems a trivial thing to do: You save the HTML content of the ```app_paragraph``` div in a variable. Then exchange the ```app_paragraph``` div with what is in your saved variable.

Comment: It's not a trivial matter for me.. Please give me a detailed explanation...